# HQL Multiple selects in the select clause

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql

I would like to get in a single query the result of multiple counts. In a native query I can do that like:

```
`select (select count(*) from Foo where status = 1), (select count(*) from Foo where status = 2) ...`
```

If I do like that in HQL:

```
select (select count(f) from Foo f where f.status = 1), (select count(f) from Foo f where f.status = 2)
```

I get an error:

```
<AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
```

How can I do that in HQL?

Answer (score 1):

Your first select is incomplete if you complete it it should be fine.

```
select (select count(f) from Foo f where f.status = 1), (select count(f) from Foo f where f.status = 2) from Foo;
```

Comment: Like that, looks like I get a matrix with as many rows as elements are in table Foo. And every line with the same result.

Comment: @JorgeBPrado Can you create MCVE and explain what is happening in a new question ? I think the problem you were facing of unexpected end of subtree is answered.